# Visa issuing country and country where the visa applies

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, check-in, air-india

I am a citizen of India and an international student in Canada. I am taking an airindia flight from India to Canada and during web check-in, they are asking for both "Visa Issuing Country" and "Country where the visa applies." I'm confused about the answers. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think they are asking because you can enter Canada on visa from US as well in which case visa issuing country and where visa applies will be different.

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut what are you talking about?  No visa from the US can substitute for any Canadian visa.

Comment: Shb1729: I'd be inclined to respond "Canada" to both.  Canada issued your visa, and your visa applies to Canada.  These things are sometimes somewhat redundant.  (The only reason I can think of right now to ask these questions separately is that some Schengen countries issue visas on behalf of other Schengen countries because of mutual representation agreements.  This is obviously not relevant to Canada, but the form design probably doesn't take that into account.)

Comment: @phoog : This is what i was refering to https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-751?language=en_US

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut the page you link to concerns the conditions under which a traveler may be "readmitted" to the US to continue the initial period of admission rather than being "admitted" a second time for a new period of admission.  I see how one might read this as implying that someone with a B visa doesn't need an additional visa for Canada, but any such implication is unintentional and the inference is in fact wrong.  Canada has a page somewhere saying this explicitly.  The only US immigration status that excuses someone from needing a visa to visit Canada is a green card.

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1020&top=16 "Do I need a Canadian visa if I have a United States visa?
Yes, most travellers need a visitor visa or an eTA to travel to, or transit through, Canada.

What you need depends on:

the type of travel document you will travel with;
the country that issued your travel document;
your nationality; and
how you will travel to Canada."

Answer (score -4):

**Visa Issuing Country:**

For this question, enter India. This is because your visa was issued by a Canadian visa office located in India, regardless of where the visa application process started. Even if you had to submit documents or attend an interview elsewhere, ultimately, the visa you hold was issued in India.

**Country where the visa applies:**

Here, enter Canada. This is because your visa is for entry into Canada. Even though you obtained it in India, its purpose is for travelling to and staying in Canada.

Therefore, your answers will be:

**Visa Issuing Country: India**

**Country where the visa applies: Canada**

Comment: India did not issue the visa. I think this covers cases where a Canadian, Schengen or US visa can be used to enter Mexico.

Comment: Thus is clearly incorrect. The country which issued the visa is Canada, not India. It may have been issued IN India, it was issued BY Canada.

Comment: I agree with the reasons stated by @phoog in comments above, and assess this answer as incorrect, and downvoted.